# Use =UNIQUE from another spreadsheet in WorkBook - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use a function (=UNIQUE ? ) to return a list of names in a range and how many names are in that range - in another worksheet. I understand this function will do this - if the data is in SAME worksheet.

Here is the link to the spreadsheet example so you can see what I mean
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fro28JD-a-ZVcWIGkzCqgNM_QEljm64FPRIVztvJTmM/edit#gid=0

I have tried query then importrange the unique but no good

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the frequency of values at the cells "A2:A" in the sheet of `CURRENT PALLETS AWAITING PROCESSING` in your shared Spreadsheet.

  - For example, in the case of value of `Pacific Magazines - Nov 2019 Donation`, you want to put `Pacific Magazines - Nov 2019 Donation` to the column "A" and the frequency of `45` to the column "B" at the other Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Flow:

The flow of this sample script is as follows.

1. Retrieve the values from the sheet.
2. Calculate the frequency.

   - Create an object and convert it to an array. And in this case, the array is sorted.
3. Put the values.

#### Sample script:

In this script, the result values are put to the sheet of `destinationSheetName` in the Spreadsheet of `destinationSpreadsheetId`. Before you run the script, please set these variables.

```
function myFunction() {
  var destinationSpreadsheetId = "###";  // Please set the destination Spreadsheet ID.
  var destinationSheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the destination sheet name of the Spreadsheet.

  var destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheetId)
  var destinationSheet = destinationSS.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);
  var sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSS.getSheetByName("CURRENT PALLETS AWAITING PROCESSING");

  // Retrieve the values from the sheet.
  var values = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();

  // Calculate the frequency.
  var obj = values.reduce(function(o, [a]) {
    // o[a] = a in o ? o[a] + 1 : 1;
    if (a) o[a] = a in o ? o[a] + 1 : 1;  // Modified
    return o;
  }, {});
  var ar = Object.keys(obj).map(function(e) {return [e, obj[e]]});

  // Put the values.
  destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, ar.length, ar[0].length).setValues(ar);
}
```

- If you want to sort the result array, please put `ar.sort(function(a, b) {return(b[1] - a[1])})` after `var ar = Object.keys(obj).map(function(e) {return [e, obj[e]]});`.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Tanaike - You have answered my question correctly and the code works just as intended. I hope to one day be able to know how to code like this.Thank you very much. Tom

Comment: Tanaike - the code does return a TOTAL which i dont need. could you let me know what I need to change to remove that. thanks

Comment: @Tom Sawkins Thank you for replying. About your additional question, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. What is `TOTAL`? Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your additional question. For example, in order to correctly understand your issue, can you update your shared Spreadsheet including the result values and your script for replicating your issue? I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Tanaike - please see link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fro28JD-a-ZVcWIGkzCqgNM_QEljm64FPRIVztvJTmM/edit#gid=0

Comment: what I realise its doing is counting the blank rows left in the sheet - something i dont need. you can see the 852 on line 13. thank you

Comment: @Tom Sawkins Thank you for replying and updating it. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your issue. When the script in my answer is used, `the 852 on line 13` cannot be seen. So I would like to confirm your current script. But, when I saw the script in your updated Spreadsheet, I cannot see your script. Can you add it to the shared Spreadsheet?

Comment: @Tom Sawkins Although I'm not sure about your current script, I modified above script. Could you please confirm it? In that case, if the empty cells are included in the retrieved values, the empty cells are ignored. If that didn't resolve your issue, I apologize. At that time, please add the script for replicating your issue. I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Tanaike - I have updated script editor. i ran it on that sheet and it didnt produce the 852 !! strange

Comment: @Tom Sawkins Thank you for replying. Although I ran your script and the shared Spreadsheet you provided, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. `the 852 on line 13` cannot be seen. By the way, I updated the script in my answer, how about this?

Comment: tanaike - i have updated script editor - tom script. all i modified was where i wanted the destination sheet to place the data.

Comment: Tanaike - that fixed it. i do appreciate your valueable time. Tom

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Very glad as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

=unique(filter(importrange("URL", "sheetName!cellRange"),importrange("URL","sheetName!cellRange") = "conditionToBeMet"))